# System.IO.IOException: 'The cloud file provider is not running

Tags: wcf, iis

.svc (wcf) project don't start on Local IIS
the project was running normally.
but when he bought a new computer, it stopped working.
It may be because iis settings have changed. How can I fix

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anIER.png)

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x8007016A
  Message=The cloud file provider is not running.

  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.get_EndOfStream()
   at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.ApplicationSettings.ReadSettingFile()
   at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.ApplicationSettings..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.ApplicationSettings.GetInstance()
   at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.UI.MainForm.ConstructRecentServiceMenuItems()
   at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.UI.MainForm..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.UI.MainForm..ctor(String[] endpoints)
   at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.Program.Main(String[] args)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there was a connectivity problem with OneDrive. The problem was solved after restarting the computer

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.